# How To Send Intent Back using ActivityLauncher API?

Tags: android, kotlin, registerforactivityresult, activity-result-api, activityresultcontracts

[I've been using this method to try to send data between Activities](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/intents/result#separate), but Google don't show you how to send the data back from the *other* Activity. So I started looking for other methods that might work, and the only thing I could find was [`Activity.setResult()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity#setResult(int)), but every time I try to run it, the intent doesn't return with anything, or that it *does*, but not in time for me to use it. I'm thinking I need an asynchronous method, but once again, Google doesn't tell you.

So I have two activities, MainActivity and Second Activity, and in Main, I have the `registerForActivityResult()` wherein I use the generic Intent version of the Contract to make the registration ([explained here](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/intents/result#custom)) Then in Second, I have a method that, on click of a TextView, makes a new Intent object, and sends the data back.

### Main Activity:

```kotlin
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    private var data: String = ""


    private val activityLauncher: ActivityResultLauncher<Intent> =
        registerForActivityResult<Intent, ActivityResult>(
            StartActivityForResult()
        ) { result: ActivityResult ->
            onActivityResult(result)
        }

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
    }

    /**
     * Switches to a different Activity
     * @return Nothing: do you see :Unit anywhere?
     * @param view: The view to Use
     */
    fun onClickSwitchActivity(view: View) {
        val editText: EditText = findViewById<EditText>(R.id.etText)
        val text: String = editText.text.toString()
        val intent: Intent = Intent(this, SecondActivity::class.java)
        intent.putExtra(REQUEST_RESULT, text)
        activityLauncher.launch(intent)
    }

    fun onActivityResult(result: ActivityResult) {
        if (result.resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
            var intent:Intent?=null
            if (result.data == null)
                Toast.makeText(this, "Intent was null: nothing returned", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
            else{
                intent = result.data
            }
            val tvReturn: TextView = findViewById<TextView>(R.id.tvReturn)
            tvReturn.text = intent?.getStringExtra(REQUEST_RESULT) ?: "-1"
            Toast.makeText(
                this, "Greetings from event result handler! This was returned: ${tvReturn.text}",
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG
            ).show()
        }
    }

    companion object {
        const val REQUEST_RESULT: String = "REQUEST_RESULT"
    }

}
```

### SecondActivity:

```kotlin
class SecondActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_second)
    }

    fun closeActivity(view: View) {
        injectIntent(42, true)
        finish()
    }

    fun injectIntent(value: Int, send: Boolean = false): Intent {
        val intent = Intent(this, MainActivity::class.java)
        intent.apply {
            putExtra(MainActivity.REQUEST_RESULT, value)
        }
        if (send) setResult(RESULT_OK, intent)
        return intent
    }

}
```

**Now, I want to clarify that I cannot use the `startActivityForResult` version of this, as that is now deprecated.**

What should I do to make this work? Am I missing something on the docs, because I've been staring at them for a week now, trying to get them to make sense.

##### UPDATE: I updated the kotlin files for the activities to better show what I'm doing or have done. Also, as per request, here's the TextView from the second activity that's controlling the return:

```xml
<TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvFinish"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:onClick="closeActivity"
        android:text="Close"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/llInput" />
```

and here's the one for `MainActivity`:

```xml
<TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvSwitch"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:onClick="onClickSwitchActivity"
        android:text="To Second Activity"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/llReturn" />
```

Comment: which method are you using while sending data back `backToFirstActivity` or `closeActivity` ?

Comment: @AgentP `closeActivity`

Comment: `tvReturn.text = intent?.getStringExtra(REQUEST_RESULT) ?: "-1"` – You did not put a `String` extra on the return `Intent`. It's an `Int` extra, so you would need to use `getIntExtra()` to retrieve it. Or change the returned extra to a `String`.

Comment: Have you tried `result.data.getIntExtra(MainActivity_REQUEST_RESULT)`?

Answer (score 1):

After recreating your app, debugging it and confusing myself thoroughly, I have an answer. For what it's worth, [here](https://github.com/MrMannWood/OnActivityResultExample) is a full, minimum, working example of what you're looking for.

Here's the bug:

- `SecondActivity` is putting an `int` into the intent
- `MainActivity` is calling `getStringExtra`

This will always return null, as there **is no** String extra with that key. `getIntExtra` is what you want.

Comment: Alright, so:
1. I used an onClick in the XAML code, that DOES, indeed, work; I just get a -1 each time I send it back.

2. I'm a little confused as to what you mean by `onActivityResult`, but I'll answer it both ways:

2a. If you mean the one I used, which isn't overridden, then I had the text setting in there, but when I debugged it, it was never able to find the TextView, which is why I started doing it in `onResume`, since that should occur after the view has been reloaded.

2b. If you mean override the ACTUAL `onActivityResult` method: I thought that was deprecated maybe?

Comment: I just noticed, when I looked at my old stuff, and yours, we're both using `getStringExtra`